# python idle 3.4.0 'print' syntax error

Tags: python, macos, printing, syntax-error

the python idle is throwing a error at the print() function im not sure why heres the code..

```
password = "cow"
name = input()
input("MR PENGUIN: hello there i am Mr Penguin  what is your name?  ")
input("well, hello there"+name+"Tell me your password")
input("You: my password is, ")
input("MR PENGUIN: im little defh could you repeat that? ")
input("YOU: my password is, "
print("PC POLICE: STOP! dont ever trust penguins with your data becuase he just told every                               one that your password is "+ password) 
input("Press Enter To Exit")
```

Comment: Oh please. You are missing a closing parenthesis in the previous line..

Comment: @thefourtheye: which is always a surprising thing to learn for newcomers; that you need to look at the previous line for the error.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a parenthesis at the end of the `input` on the prior line.

Change:

```
input("YOU: my password is, "
```

to:

```
input("YOU: my password is, ")
```

---

For the record, your `print` was fine. Note that when you get a cryptic error, it is often something on the *previous line*.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `input` statement in the previous line is missing a closing paranthesis.

It should be:

```
input("YOU: my password is, ")
```

instead of

```
input("YOU: my password is, "
```